# FileSystemWatcher and write completion

Tags: c#

I am implementing an event handler that must open and process the content of a file created by a third part application over which I have no control. I am warned by a note in "C# 4.0 in a nutshell" (page 495) about the risk to open a file before it is fully populated; so I am wondering how to manage this occurrence. To keep at minimum the load on the event handler,  I am considering to have the handler simply insert in a queue the file names and then to have a different thread to manage the processing, but, anyways, how may I make sure that the write is completed and the file read is safe? The file size could be arbitrary.

Some idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reliable way to achieve what you want might be to use FileSystemWatcher + NTFS USN journal.
Maybe more complicated than you expected, but FileSystemWatcher alone won't tell you for sure that the newly created file has been closed

-first, the FileSystemWatcher, to know when a file is created. From there you have the complete file path, and are 1 or 2 pinvokes away from getting the file unique ID (which can help you to track it during its whole lifetime).

-then, read the USN journal, which tracks everything that occurs on your drive. Filter on entries corresponding to your new file's ID, and read the journal until reaching the entry with the 'Close' event.

From there, unless your file is manipulated in special ways (opened and closed multiple times by the application that generates it), you can assume it is safe to read it and do whatever you wanted to do with it.

A really great C# implementation of an USN journal parser is StCroixSkipper's work, available here:
http://mftscanner.codeplex.com/

If you are interested I can give you more help about USN journal, as I use it in my project.

Comment: Actually, a dirtier but cheaper/easier way to achieve more or less the same thing would be to do what's being suggested in [this SO linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588605/is-file-being-copied-right-now#comment16964757_12588605)

Comment: merci bien pur ton aide, c'est trés interessant. Bien sur j'irai te demender de l'aide si j'aurai besoin de comprendre quelque chose de plus.

Answer (score 1):

Our workaround is to watch for a specific extension. When a file is uploaded, the extension is ".tmp". When its done uploading, it's renamed to have the proper extension.

Another alternative is to have the server try to move the file in a try/catch block. If the fie isn't done being uploaded, the attempt to move the file will throw an exception, so we wait and try again.

Comment: I forgot to specify: the program is not a client server one, it works on a desktop, so I guess that none the hints could work... or am I wrong?

Comment: Both will work in a desktop app. The issues are the same, and the workarounds are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you can't know.  If the other applications "write" operation is to open the file denying write access to everyone else then when it's done, close the file.  When you get a notification then you could simply open the file requesting write access and if that fails, you know the operation isn't complete.  But, if the "write" operation is to open the file, write, close the file, open the file again, and write again, etc., then you're pretty much out of luck.

The best solution I've seen is to set a timer after the last notification.  When the timer elapses, try to open the file for write--if you can, assume the "operation" is done and do what you need to do.  If the open fails, assume the operation is still in progress and wait some more.

Of course, nothing is foolproof.  Despite the above, another operation could start while you're doing what you want with the file and cause interaction problems.