# how to check a file is copy completed in c# without opening the file

Tags: c#

I need to check a file is finished copying in C#. Is there any event like iscopycompleted ? I need to check without opening the file. Many of the samples shows by opening the file.

When do the attributes of the file is created? What is the attribute of the file while it under copying? Is there any way to check the file is copying by using file attributes?

I have checked using the following code.

```
FileAttribute atr=File.getAttribute("FilePath");
```

I got the fileattribute as Archive while copying and after copy completed.

Comment: how is the copy initiated?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588605/is-file-being-copied-right-now

Comment: Well you know when the code is (succesfully) executed and there was no exception thrown.

Comment: I am trying folder watcher. Here I am watching a folder if a file enters a folder I need to move it to another. If I move the file which is not fully copied I got error like Another process is using the file. So i need to check whether the file is fully copied.I doesn't need to use file.open and keep on checking.

Comment: Consider using `FileSystemWatcher` class.It raises events when changes are made to file directory.

Comment: Yes I am using FilesystemWatcher only but the Changed event rises when the File is changed or sizes increased.But it doesn't say of file copy completed.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare the size of two files

```
long length1 = new System.IO.FileInfo("fromFile").Length;

//code for moving file here

long length2;
do{
    length2 = new System.IO.FileInfo("toFile").Length;
} while (length1!=length2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function keep working until the file is finished copying.

```
private bool CheckFileHasCopied(string FilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
                using (File.OpenRead(FilePath))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            return CheckFileHasCopied(FilePath);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if we are copying multiple files at once? How could we know how many files are to be copied and start processing after all files are finished copying?

Comment: There's no problem if you coppying multiple, but when you need to process the files then you can used CheckFileHasCopied. You can used [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) to detect and count every file that's come inside the folder and processing once it's finished copying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for, Just control FileSystemWatcher Created Event:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    bool flag = true;
    while(flag)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move(e.FullPath, @"C:\NewLocation\" + e.Name);
            flag = false;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check whether file has been moved from one location to other location, then you can do something like this.

```
//Store the location of your destination folder here with FileName
string Destination = "Destination_Location/"+FileName;

//Now get the entire Destination Address with FileName using Server.MapPath
string FullPath = Server.MapPath(Destination );

//Now you can use File.Exists condition to check whether file is present in your Destination location or not    
if (File.Exists(FullPath))
{
   //File copy is completed
}
else
{
   //File not present
}
```

Comment: Not a good way. Because The file will exist there but it is in use by other processes. So File.Exists returns true but the file is in use and can not be moved.

Comment: I just gave the logic to move the file once all action on the file is completed, and later he can move the file. To check if file is moved or not in destination, he can use File.Exists method. If it returns true that means file has successfully moved to destination. If it returns false, that means file is not copied, that time he can again try to move the file